# Calculate modularity using networkx

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

Creating a graph with nodes that have attribute `Race`, which could be either `dog` `car` `elephant` or `giraffe`, which is then sorted into four lists (four communities). See code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx

df = pd.read_csv(path + 'raw_data.csv')

G = nx.Graph()

for i in range(len(df)):
    node = df.Name.values[i]
    race = df.Race.values[i]
    
    G.add_nodes_from([(node, {"Race":race})])

dog = [x for x,y in G.nodes(data=True) if y['Race']=='Dog']
cat = [x for x,y in G.nodes(data=True) if y['Race']=='Cat']
elephant = [x for x,y in G.nodes(data=True) if y['Race']=='Elephant']
giraffe = [x for x,y in G.nodes(data=True) if y['Race']=='Giraffe']
```

Then I want to calculate modularity, using networkx like this example:

```
import networkx.algorithms.community as nx_comm

G = nx.barbell_graph(3, 0)
nx_comm.modularity(G, [{0, 1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}])
```

Is it possible to add the four lists into the modularity function as the communities? or is there some other way to do this?

All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following?

```
nx_comm.modularity(G, [set(race) for race in (dog, cat, elephant, giraffe)])
```

Comment: Doesn't work, but thanks for the help anyway :)

Comment: What is the error, @lo7?